# Mapped types in Scala similar to Typescript Pick, Exclude, etc

Tags: typescript, scala, derived-types, mapped-types

Following on the heels of [Mapped types in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700613/mapped-types-in-scala)

Is there a way to mimic `Pick`, `Exclude`, `Diff` and etc. from Typescript in Scala?

Using the a similar example as above:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, address: String, phone: String)
```

is there a way to derive a type

```
class PersonSubset(name: String, age: Int)
```

without having to explicitly write out a separate case class?

As in following more of a Typescript approach, could we create a type alias that is a subset of fields of class `Person`?

Comment: I'm interested in this too.  Examples would be `SELECT name, age FROM Person` or GraphQL.