# Is there any equivalent to TypeScript's Partial<T> type in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish the work that `Partial<T>` does in TypeScript in scala.

Specifically, for a given case class like

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: String, c: String)
```

Is there a way to derive a case class like

```scala
case class PartialFoo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])
```

in a way that I could construct a `PartialFoo` without having to declare it?

Comment: You could do something like: `final case class BaseFoo[F[_]](a: F[String], b: F[String], c: F[String])` and then `type Foo = BaseFoo[Id]` & `type PartialFoo = BaseFoo[Option]`.

Comment: Take a look at the `shapeless` library. But barring the dark magic in that library/macros, no. Scala generally does not have compile-time mechanisms for taking types apart to their fields and making new ones.

Comment: I'm also dubious on why one would ever need a record type where every field is optional.

Comment: Maybe trying to merge two case classes using upsert semantics. Perhaps trying to emulate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically. Interesting snippet by Krzysztof might be of interest  [Generically update case class using another case class with Shapeless](https://gist.github.com/katlasik/a9309e310c220827552e99d60bb92866)

Comment: @LeviRamsey this question is geared towards succinct syntax for use in unit testing.  I have some classes that interact/relate on just a few fields. I want to test code that joins/relates those fields, but don't want the unit tests to have to dilute intent/readability on filling in dozens of unrelated fields. This is a pretty unique situation involving spark DataFrames, but I find this case illuminating in regards to learning scala and its abilities

Comment: Another use case would be SQL and GraphQL, e.g.:

`SELECT name, address FROM people`
`SELECT name, address, birthdate FROM people`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727388/mapped-types-in-scala-similar-to-typescript-pick-exclude-etc#comment123874563_59727388