# Generic recursive type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

Having just started to dip my toes with Scala and am now looking to understand whether there is any way to express Deep partial types (recursive types) in Scala?

**###################### Update ######################**

What I am trying to achieve is to take an existing case class and somehow "Version" it, such that it recursively adds that to every field even at deeply nested levels

e.g. lets assume I have these classes defined

```scala
case class A(p1: Int, p2: Int, ..)
case class B(p1: Map[String, A])
case class C(param1: String, param2: String, param3: Option[B])
```

I want to `version` **C**, which means for every parameter type (recursively) I want an optional `version: Int` to be added.

The naive way, I see, would be to define a new class `VersionedValue` and then manually redefine all of the existing types to accommodate this.

e.g. what it may look like

```scala
case class VersionedValue [A](value: A, version: Option[Int])

case class A(p1: VersionedValue[Int], p2: VersionedValue[Int])

case class B(p1: Map[String, VersionedValue[A]])

case class C(p1: VersionedValue[String], 
             p2: VersionedValue[String],
             p3: Option[B])
```

####################################################

Having worked with TypeScript for a while, that usually would look something like this:

```js
/** 
* the VersionedDeepPartial<T> will recursively iterate through 
* each of the "keys" (or attributes) and for each creates a new
* object that adds a version field. The value attribute will hold 
* what was originally the type for the key.
*/
export type VersionedDeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: {value: VersionedDeepPartial<T[P]>; version?:number}
};

// So if I had an interface (in typescript) looking like:

interface A {
  p1: number,
  p2: number,
}

interface B {
   [key: string]: A
}

interface C {
   p1: String,
   p2: String,
   p3: B
}

/**
* Note that interface C does not define any versioning attribute to
* its fields. But by wrapping the type within the 
*/
VersionedDeepPartial<T>

const partialFoo: VersionedDeepPartial<C> = {
    p1: { value: "asdf", version: 1 },
    p2: { value: "asdf" },
    p3: {
        "somekey": {
           p1: {value: 1, version: 1},
           p2: {value: 2}
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want is to define a new type by recursing through an existing type/class definition and "injecting" versioning to it.

I've read/browsed around for explanations on this topic with no success. Is this possible to express in Scala?

Comment: I think this requires macros or a library like shapeless. It would be interesting to know whether any features in Scala 3 could be used to implement this (`Mirror`?).

Comment: I'm curious what problem you are trying to solve exactly, with this? I suspect there is a better statically-typed way of solving the problem in Scala.

Comment: There is recursive type in Scala, but as many of us cant read TS, it might be worthwhile to explain a little more what those code does so we can help you better

Comment: Hey, updated the text a bit to try making it clearer @JackLeow

Comment: @texasbruce ^  the TS code especially the DeepPartial type definition is a way to effectively make each attribute within an existing type optional. This then allows you to instantiate or validate partial data for a type. 

For my use case, I want to avoid copy paste the type definition that exists for my complex type. Since that is pretty much achievable in TS, but haven't found a way in scala

Comment: Your requirement is not of a recursive type but of a something which can dynamicly adopt classes and versionify them. Might be possible with Scala macros.

Comment: Not sure I understand why this wouldn't have a recursive requirement? In the TypeScript example given, its would recursively go through each object attribute type, only that I wrap it to add the versioning. 

In the scala example, I would still need each member of case class C to be versioned, and their members as well need to be versioned and so on. the model that I am working on can have as many as 5-7 levels of nested types. Not familiar with macros, but will have a look at it @sarveshseri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700613/mapped-types-in-scala/

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want Higher Kinded Data approach:

```
case class HKDA[F[_]](p1: F[Int], p2: F[Int], ..)
case class HKDB[F[_]](p1: Map[String, HKDA[F]])
case class HKDC[F[_]](param1: F[String], param2: F[String], param3: Option[HKDB[F]])

type Id[A] = A
type A = HKDA[Id]
type B = HKDB[Id]
type C = HKDC[Id]

case class Versioned[A](a: A, version: Int)
type VersionedA = HKDA[Versioned]
type VersionedB = HKDB[Versioned]
type VersionedC = HKDC[Versioned]
```